# rworldmap package - Keeping the lower xlim in a sequence of maps, but the left regions are changing

Tags: r, maps, rworldmap

I'm trying to create an animation composed of a sequence of maps. At one stage of this animation I needed to keep the left extremity of the map and only extend it far right. To do so I kept the `xlim` lower limit fixed and changed only the `xlim` upper limit.

```
library(rworldmap)

worldMap <- getMap(resolution = "high")

fixedLatitude <- c(36.76, 38.76)

# Fixed lower limit of the X axis
fixedMinLongitude <- 20.64
# Varying the upper limit of the X axis 
maxLongitudes <- seq(22.64, 22.78498, length.out = 4)
longitudes <- lapply(maxLongitudes, function(x) c(fixedMinLongitude, x))

countMaps <- 1
for (ln in longitudes){
  png(paste("test", countMaps, ".png", sep = ""))
  mapCountryData(worldMap,
                 xlim = ln,
                 ylim = fixedLatitude,
                 addLegend = F, mapTitle = "")

  dev.off()
  countMaps <- countMaps + 1
}
```

I expected that the regions to the left of the map would not change in the four figures. That is, the contours of these would not be cut off from the map. But the [result I got was this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hkw0.jpg).

In these sequences it can be seen that the edge of the island on the left is being changed because the map is "walking" to the right and not only expading to the right as I expected to.

Where am I going wrong?

#### A more extreme example (with vertical lines)

```
library(rworldmap)

worldMap <- getMap(resolution = "high")

fixedLatitude <- c(36.76, 38.76)

# Fixed lower limit of the X axis
fixedMinLongitude <- 20.64
# Varying the upper limit of the X axis 
maxLongitudes <- seq(22, 25, length.out = 4)
longitudes <- lapply(maxLongitudes, function(x) c(fixedMinLongitude, x))

proportionLeftSpace <- seq(0,0, length.out = 4)
countMaps <- 1
for (ln in longitudes){
  png(paste("test", countMaps, ".png", sep = ""))
  mapCountryData(worldMap,
                  xlim = ln,
                  ylim = fixedLatitude,
                  addLegend = F, mapTitle = "")
 abline(v = ln)

 plotRegionMinX <- par("usr")[1]
 spaceBeforeXlim <-  ln[1] -  plotRegionMinX
 onePercentXAxis <- diff(ln)/100
 proportionLeftSpace[countMaps] <- spaceBeforeXlim/onePercentXAxis 

 dev.off()
 countMaps <- countMaps + 1
}

proportionLeftSpace
```

[The result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORoi4.jpg)

In this example the transition between the first and the second map have the problem I had mentioned, however, the transition between the other maps is what I desire.

Following the suggestion of Andy, I added vertical lines. This showed me that there is a greater distance between the lower threshold of the `xlim` and the "plot region" in the first map. To corroborate this I added the `proportionLeftSpace`  variable that stores the percentage of space left before bottom `xlim`. The result of it is:

```
39.28339  4.00000  4.00000  4.00000
```

So, there is a 10 times greater space before the `xlim` in the first map than in the others.

Comment: The size of the plot area is constant. Therefore if you change the right extent while keeping the left extent constant the scale of the map must change. Is that what you want ? This isn't very clear in your example. If you could recreate a more extreme example it might be clearer how to fix it. You can add this into your loop to see where the xlim & ylim you specify fit into the plot area.   `abline(v=ln)
abline(h=fixedLatitude)` Happy to give more help if needed.

Comment: @Andy Hi Andy, thanks for the response and the great job with the package. Yes, that's exactly what I want. I updated the post with a more extreme example and added vertical lines. In this example, it can be seen that between the first and second map the left part of the map is changed. The same does not occur in other transitions (that's what I wanted to happen in all). It turns out that in the first case there is more space between the bottom of the ``xlim`` and the bottom limit of the plot region (``par(usr[1])``). You know why this happens? Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@celacanto Excellent! Thanks for the clarification in the question and helping me to understand exactly how R & therefore `rworldmap` deals with plot extents.

The short answer to your question :
There is a bigger gap between the left `xlim` and the left plot boundary in your first plot because the `ylim` is larger relative to the `xlim` and therefore determining the scale of the plot. This is demonstrated in the fig below where `ylim` determines the scale in the upper 2 plots and `xlim` determines the scale in the lower 2 plots.

[image: larger x border because ylim determines scale in upper two plots]

The solution is to make `ylim` smaller relative to `xlim` as shown in the code below and that should mean that the left plot border will not move as in this plot :
[image: x border constant because xlim determines scale in all plots]

```
library(rworldmap)

#worldMap <- getMap(resolution = "high")
#this makes it quicker & illustrates the same thing
worldMap <- getMap(resolution="low")

#fixedLatitude <- c(36.76, 38.76)
#making the latitudinal difference smaller
#so that the longitudinal difference always determines map scale
fixedLatitude <- c(36.76, 37.76)

# Fixed lower limit of the X axis
fixedMinLongitude <- 20.64
# Varying the upper limit of the X axis 
maxLongitudes <- seq(22, 25, length.out = 4)
longitudes <- lapply(maxLongitudes, function(x) c(fixedMinLongitude, x))

#create blank object to store left space
proportionLeftSpace <- seq(0,0, length.out = 4)

#alternative to put all 4 plots together on windows, comment out png & dev.off
#windows()
#op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

countMaps <- 1
for (ln in longitudes){
  png(paste("xlimtest", countMaps, ".png", sep = ""))
  mapCountryData(worldMap,
                 xlim = ln,
                 ylim = fixedLatitude,
                 addLegend = F, mapTitle = "")


  abline(v=ln)
  abline(h=fixedLatitude)

  #from celacanto
  plotRegionMinX <- par("usr")[1]
  spaceBeforeXlim <-  ln[1] -  plotRegionMinX
  onePercentXAxis <- diff(ln)/100
  proportionLeftSpace[countMaps] <- spaceBeforeXlim/onePercentXAxis

  dev.off()
  countMaps <- countMaps + 1
}

proportionLeftSpace
```

In this example `proportionLeftSpace` comes out as a constant 4,4,4,4 which is the default set by R.

Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: Knowing this  helped me to avoid the problem, thanks. After this response I made some internet search and I'm assuming this behavior have something to do with the ``asp`` parameter, correct?